# Expo error while choosing template: Could not get npm url for package

Tags: javascript, react-native, ubuntu, expo, linux-mint

Error:

```
Laptop:~/Documents/react$ expo init PasswordManager
✔ Choose a template: › blank               a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas
✖ Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.
Could not get npm url for package "expo-template-blank"
```

I am trying to set up React Native in my Linux Mint. I tried using `sudo expo init PasswordManager` but it was same, I tried doing `sudo npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and `npm install expo-template-blank`

Node version: v16.14.0

Edit: I tried reinstalling expo but no change

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I has installed node using snap.

I uninstalled it then used this to install a more recent version of node:

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

And then everything worked.

If `apt` isn't available to you (because you arent on Ubuntu or similar) then you should still be installing node from nodesource.

Also worth noting, expo might not be tested against the latest greatest node.

At time or writing the active LTS version of expo needs a node version of >=14.0.0 <15.0.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case Node was installed using Ubuntu Software

I have reinstalled using [node js respo](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) for ubuntu.

So it started Working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded the Node version to 12.x and it worked!!

```
sudo apt -y install curl dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash
```

Then reinstall expo
`npm uninstall -g expo-cli`

`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli`

Now you can youse expo init!